# Program is treating the same string differently when entered into a different text box

Tags: javascript, html, dom, local-storage

I have a program that is supposed to group links together. Like minecraft saved toolbars, you can save a collection of links, then enter in the name of a group and it will open all of them.

But my program is having trouble with getting the list from localStorage when the name is entered into the text box meant to get the link. But when I just use the value of the text box meant to *name* the group, it works fine.

My code is here:

```js
var groupName = document.getElementById('name');
var link = document.getElementById('newLink');
var linkCounter = 0
var getByName = document.getElementById('getByName').value

function startGroup() {
  localStorage.setItem(groupName.value, groupName.value);
  console.log(localStorage.getItem(groupName.value))
}

function addLink() {
  linkCounter++;
  localStorage.setItem(groupName.value + '_link' + linkCounter, link.value);
  console.log(localStorage.getItem(groupName.value + '_link' + linkCounter))
}

function saveGroup() {
  localStorage.setItem(groupName.value + '_length', linkCounter);
  console.log(localStorage.getItem(groupName.value + '_length'))
  alert(groupName.value);
}

function getGroup() {
  // if I replace getByName with groupName.value, it works fine. 
  var len = localStorage.getItem(getByName + '_length')
  console.log(len)
  for (var x = 1; x <= len; x++) {
    window.open(localStorage.getItem(getByName + '_link' + x));
  }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<a href='readit.html'>READ THIS BEFORE USING</a>
<p>WHEN ADDING A LINK YOU NEED TO PASTE IT OR ADD HTTPS:// TO THE BEGINNING OF THE LINK.</p>
<div id='toolbars'>
  <p>Open a group!</p>
</div>
<div id='create'>
  <p>Create some bookmark groups!</p>
  <input type='text' placeholder='name your group' id='name'>
  <button onclick='startGroup()'>Let's add some links!</button>
  <br>
  <input type='text' placeholder='add a link' id='newLink'>
  <button onclick='addLink()'>Submit</button>
  <br>
  <button onclick='saveGroup()'>SAVE</button>
</div>

<div id='preview'>
  <br><br>
  <button onclick='getGroup()'>Open this group</button>
  <input type="text" id="getByName">
</div>

</html>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading the value of the `getByName` input element at *page load*. Instead you should read the value at the time of need. So define `getByName` as the DOM element (not as its value):

```
var getByName = document.getElementById('getByName');
```

And where you currently reference `getByName`, suffix the `.value` property accessor. For instance:

```
var len = localStorage.getItem(getByName.value + '_length');
```

Side note: I find it easier to use a memory data structure for all your data, and when something is added to it, to write that complete data structure to one single local storage key, JSON formatted. You may want to look into that.

Comment: This is great, but why does it open like 3 other tabs when i run it from the repl? https://repl.it/@EthanBlesch/BookmarkGroups#script.js

Comment: Because you call `window.open` in a loop? Was that not what you wanted? If not, then don't perform that loop...

Comment: i mean the three tabs i wanted then three 'not found' tabs

Comment: I don't know... did you debug, what the URL was that you gave to `window.open`? Are they valid?

Comment: okay, so the program is effectively running window.open(null) once for every iteration of the for loop.

Comment: So what did you provide as `getByName.value` and what did you provide as `groupName.value` earlier on? Do they match? ... I mean, this is the debugging you need to do: inspect variables, step through the code, set break points, ...etc.

Comment: okay, i found the problem. I didn't add code to reset the value of linkCounter after a set is saved, and the set  i was testing with was created in the same session as another set.